# Inside fixed position div, absolute elements not going outside of div

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar which is position fixed. there is some span elements i want to show on outside of div on hover.

Everything work well but if i add `overflow-y: scroll` or auto. 
absolute elements stay in div area, can't go outside of div.

i tried to simulate my problem here in codepen. 
if you will delete overflow property from **sidebar** you will see some text span will go outside of div how i want to be

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgExZY#anon-login

Comment: In your codepen u haven't added any code for hover,then elements will hover could please explain it clearly ?

Comment: this is bydesign and you cannot avoid it unless you make the element fixed too

Comment: Yes i didn't add there hover. It's not important. there is just i'm explain when sidebar have overflow scroll span element can't stay outside of yellow zone

Comment: If you set the `div` `overflow: visible;` you see it outside of the `div`. Maybe you should somehow toggle this css property on hover?

Comment: yes but that time i can't scroll sidebar content

Comment: can anybody help me with this?